# how to align big text beside image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am creating product detail page on html on one div i have an image and on other i have details of product when i am adding big text on the detail paragraph whole div is coming under the image div can someone tell why is it keep happening? is it becuase of size of div is not defined
[after adding big text on it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMHQX.png)

[before adding big text on it

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
  
}
a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none !important;
}
.small-paragraph2, .small-paragraph1{
    margin: 0;
}
.container {
    min-width: 90%;
    margin: auto;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
    margin-top: 25px;
   
  
}
.product-image{
    width:400px;
    display:block;
    height: 400px;
}


.details {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0; 
    vertical-align:top;
    
}

 .intro .text{
     line-height: 0.8;
 }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
          
            <div style="display:inline-block;" >
                    <img class="product-image" src="/images/ruach-1.png" style="display:inline-block;">
                </div>
                <div class="details">
                 
                    <div class="intro">
                    <h3 class="text"><strong>Ruach 5781(AUDIO)</strong></h3>
                    <h4 class="text">New Jewish Tune</h4>
                    </div>

                    <h5>By <a asp-action="index" asp-controller="home">Various Artist</a>  Produced by
                      <a asp-action="index" asp-controller="home"> Joel English</a></h5>
                    <h6>Item: 955016DA</h6>
                    <button class="pro-button"><strong>Print Songbook with Audio</strong><br />$19.95</button>
                    <button class="pro-button"><strong>PDF Songbook</strong><br />$19.95</button>
                    <button class="pro-button"><strong>Digital Album</strong><br />$19.95</button>
                    <span class="minus wrapper" style="color:grey;">-</span>
                    <span class="num wrapper" style="color:grey;">1</span>
                    <span class="plus wrapper" style="color:grey;">+</span>
                     <a asp-action="index" asp-controller="home" class="myButton" style="border: 0px;"><i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i>Add to Cart</a>
                     <a asp-action="" asp-controller="" style="display:inline-block;" class="addtolist">Add to List <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></a>
                    <p class="small-paragraph1"><strong>10% off </strong>distracted by the readable content ofs layout.</p>
                    <p class="small-paragraph2">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting . Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                        when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has 
                        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially 
                        unchanged.is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting . Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, 
                        when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has 
                        survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially 
                        unchanged.
                    </p>
                
                 </div>
```

][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8mKBx.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: flex;` to `.container`.

```css
html {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 100%;
  min-width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin-bottom: 60px;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none !important;
}

.small-paragraph2,
.small-paragraph1 {
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 25px;
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.product-image {
  width: 400px;
  display: block;
  height: 400px;
}

.details {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.intro .text {
  line-height: 0.8;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div style="display:inline-block;">
    <img class="product-image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" style="display:inline-block;">
  </div>
  <div class="details">
    <div class="intro">
      <h3 class="text"><strong>Ruach 5781(AUDIO)</strong></h3>
      <h4 class="text">New Jewish Tune</h4>
    </div>
    <h5>By <a asp-action="index" asp-controller="home">Various Artist</a> Produced by
      <a asp-action="index" asp-controller="home"> Joel English</a></h5>
    <h6>Item: 955016DA</h6>
    <button class="pro-button"><strong>Print Songbook with Audio</strong><br />$19.95</button>
    <button class="pro-button"><strong>PDF Songbook</strong><br />$19.95</button>
    <button class="pro-button"><strong>Digital Album</strong><br />$19.95</button>
    <span class="minus wrapper" style="color:grey;">-</span>
    <span class="num wrapper" style="color:grey;">1</span>
    <span class="plus wrapper" style="color:grey;">+</span>
    <a asp-action="index" asp-controller="home" class="myButton" style="border: 0px;"><i class="fa-solid fa-bag-shopping"></i>Add to Cart</a>
    <a asp-action="" asp-controller="" style="display:inline-block;" class="addtolist">Add to List <i class="fa-solid fa-caret-down"></i></a>
    <p class="small-paragraph1"><strong>10% off </strong>distracted by the readable content ofs layout.</p>
    <strong>Description: </strong>
    <p class="small-paragraph2">is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting . Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
      five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting . Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer
      took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```